# responding to user tapping notification - bring up relevant view controller

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to have my app automatically navigate to a notifications view that will display the notification that was sent to the user.

To put it briefly, I have a series of `UIViewController` objects defining the login process, which links to a `UITabViewController` if login was successful. Within the `UITabViewController` are 5 attached `UIViewControllers`.

When a user taps a notification banner, I'd like the screen to display the **fourth** `UIViewController`. I've been tinkering with this method for a while, trying to display the VC upon a user tapping the notification:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
  let rootViewController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController //the rootVC in the storyboard
  let welcomeVC = rootViewController.topViewController as! WelcomeVC //welcome page
  let loginVC = welcomeVC... //welcomeVC has a segue to this 

  //after loginVC is the UITabViewController
  //I want to show the 4th VC of the UITabViewController when user taps the notification
}
```

I'm afraid this approach isn't going to work. In particular, I also have the problem of dealing with 2 different scenarios:

1. User taps the notification while the app is not in memory
2. User taps the notification while the app is in memory

Thanks in advance for the advice!

Comment: I'm not clear on what the question is here?

Answer (score 0):

If the app is in memory, the method you posted will be called.

If the app is not in memory, you have to rely on the method `application(_,didFinishLoadingWithOptions)`. In `launchOptions` you can check the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` to get the notification.

What I usually do when the app is in memory and I have a navigation controller is call `popToRootViewController` without animation and then push the controllers animating only the last one.

If your child VCs are linked with segues you cannot use them in code (because they animate). Instead, you have to use the storyboard's `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` and push/present them in code, passing the necessary attributes as necessary (similar to what you do in `prepareForSegue`).

Comment: I understand how to check the key and get the notification payload. What I don't know is how to display a particular view controller as a result of the user tapping the notification and launching the app

Comment: You can do the same at the end of didFinishLaunghingWithOptions.

Comment: My hierarchy of VCs is root > welcome > login > tab > 5 child VCs. I need to reach the 4th child VC as a result of responding to the remote notification.

Comment: I added some guidance on how to proceed here to my answer.